# Handling notifications in view controller or a subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, nsnotifications

I wonder what the optimal way is to respond to notifications sent out by the notification centers.

Here is an example:
I have a model which receives updates from the server.
Whenever new information is received a notification is generated and posted though the `NSNotificationCenter`.

There is a view controller with lots of (partially nested) subviews; depending on the type of information received I have to update a particular subview.

For me, there are currently two solutions:

1. The view controller becomes observer and tells a particular view to update based on the notification name. `[subviewx pleaseUpdate];`
2. Each view registers an a observer and depending on the notification name.

The downside of 1 is that the vc has to deal with all notifications although he is not really affected.

Is there any proposed way to do this? Should the responsible view controller deal with all notifications or is it ok for a `UILabel`, for instance, to become an observer and be somewhat independent.

Thanks for your opinion!

Answer (score 1):

An interesting question - technically, both approaches produce the same result.

However, personally I'd lean towards keeping your notification handling in the view controller, because that's closer to the model-view-controller (MVC) pattern in iOS.

The other advantage of having your notification in the view controller is that you may want to reuse your views elsewhere in your app, and you don't want adverse side effects happening when views start responding to notifications they weren't intended to receive. Collating all your notifications in the view controller will also make handling them much easier - don't forget you need to remove your notification observers when you're done with the view, and having all your `removeObserver` statements in one place is arguably far better than spread across multiple classes.